# Отрисовка объектов в массиве react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

При добавлении товаров в корзину, хочу чтоб одинаковые товары (с одинаковыми id) отрисовывались по одному разу.

### Корзина:

```
import React from 'react'
import './Cart.css'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

import basket from '../../common/img/shopping-cart-black.svg';
import trash from '../../common/img/trash.svg';
import back from '../../common/img/back.svg';
import emptyCart from '../../common/img/empty-cart.svg';
import { clearPizzaCartAC, removePizzaAC } from '../../redux/cart-reducer';
import CartItem from './CartItem';
import Form from './Form/Form';

const Cart = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const { items, totalCount, totalPrice } = useSelector(({ cart }) => ({
    items: cart.items,
    totalPrice: cart.totalPrice,
    totalCount: cart.totalCount
  }))

  const [isOrder, setIsOrder] = React.useState(false)

  const onClickRemovePizza = (pizzaId) => {
    dispatch(removePizzaAC(pizzaId))
  }
  const onClickClearCart = () => {
    dispatch(clearPizzaCartAC())
  }
  
  return  (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="content">
        { isOrder && (<Form setIsOrder={setIsOrder} 
                            onClickClearCart={onClickClearCart}
                            items={items} 
                            totalCount={totalCount} 
                            totalPrice={totalPrice} />) }
        <div className="container container--cart">
          <div className="cart">
            {
              items.length ?
              ( // Если в корзине что-то есть
                <>
                  <div className="cart__top">
                    <h2 className="content__title"> <img src={basket} className="bask svg" alt="basket" /> Корзина</h2>
                    <div className="cart__clear" onClick={() => {
                      let popup = window.confirm("Вы уверены, что хотите очистить корзину?") 
                      popup && dispatch(clearPizzaCartAC())
                    } }>
                      <img src={trash} alt="trash" />
                      <span>Очистить корзину</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="content__items">

                  {items.map((item, index) => {
                    // const identicalsId = items.filter( elem => elem.id === item.id)
                    return ( 
                      <CartItem key={index} onClickRemovePizza={onClickRemovePizza} {...item} />
                    )
                  })}

                  </div>
                  <div className="cart__bottom">
                    <div className="cart__bottom-details">
                      <span> Всего пицц: <b>{totalCount} шт.</b> </span>
                      <span> Сумма заказа: <b>{totalPrice} ₽</b> </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="cart__bottom-buttons">
                      <NavLink to='/catalog'>
                        <img src={back} className="svg back" alt="back" />
                        <span>Вернуться назад</span>
                      </NavLink>
                      <div className="button pay-btn">
                        <button className="btn-order" onClick={ () => setIsOrder(true) }>Заказать</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </>
              ) :
              ( // Если корзина пустая
                <div className="empty_cart">
                  <h2>Корзина пустая</h2>
                  <p>Вероятней всего, вы не заказывали ещё пиццу.
                     Для того, чтобы заказать пиццу, перейди на главную страницу.</p>
                     <img src={emptyCart} alt="empty-cart-logo" className="empty-cart-logo" />
                     <NavLink to='/catalog'>
                        <button>Вернуться назад</button>
                     </NavLink>
                </div>
              )
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cart
```

### Товары:

```
import React from 'react'

import minus from '../../common/img/minus.svg';
import plus from '../../common/img/plus.svg';
import closeCart from '../../common/img/close-cart.svg';

const CartItem = ({ id, image, title, activeSize, activePrice, onClickRemovePizza }) => {
  const onRemovePizza = () => {
    const pizzaId = id
    onClickRemovePizza(pizzaId)
  }

  return (
    <div className="cart__item">
      <div className="cart__item-img">
        <img className="pizza-block__image"
          src={image}
          alt={title} />
      </div>
      <div className="cart__item-info">
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <p>{activeSize}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="cart__item-count">
        <div  onClick={onRemovePizza} className="button button--outline button--circle cart__item-count-minus"> 
        <img src={minus} className="svg minus" alt="minus" />
      </div>
      <b>1</b>
      <div className="button button--outline button--circle cart__item-count-plus"> 
        <img src={plus} className="svg" alt="plus" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="cart__item-price">
      <b>{price}</b>
    </div>
    <div className="cart__item-remove">
      <div className="button button--outline button--circle" onClick={ () => onRemovePizza }> 
        <img src={closeCart} className="close-cart svg" alt="closeCart" /> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}

export default CartItem
```

Стейт вернул массив с 3 объектами, у двух одинаковые id. И не могу понять, как сделать чтоб в корзине они шли по одному в строке, но счетчик показывал сколько их.

[image]

Comment: А можно посмотреть на экшен добавления в корзину? Мне кажется вы просто пушите товар в корзину. Хотя правильней было бы если в корзине уже есть этот товар то менять его параметры количества и цены. Так как если делать уникальный массив. То процесс удаления будет работать не правильно.